# I have to deploy war files into azure Linux using azure devops so i have created environment in azure devops then copied PS script from azure devopss

Tags: azure-devops

I have to deploy war files into azure Linux using azure devops so I have created environment in azure devops then copied PS script from azure devops then ran the ps script in Azure Linux Vm then i am getting issues like no space left on device.
[image]

Comment: The filesystem in use does not have enough space.'

Comment: Either use a different filesystem or increase the space of current filesystem.

Comment: HI , I have enough space in Azure Linux Vm